# How to format a large Number

Tags: formatting

There is a large number

```
a = 123456789012345678901234567.123456789012345678901234567
```

By format with AccountingForm

```
b = AccountingForm[a, 54]
```

it becomes

```
123456789012345678901234567.123456789012345678901234567
```

How to to parameterise the integer part and the fractional and the
n-digit precision part to produce a number. Like

```
int=123456789012345678901234567.  
fra=.123456789012345678901234567  
pre=54
```

resulting to the same outcome like b above?

**UPDATE**

A general solution was found.

```
int = 1234567890123456789012345678900;
fra = 123456789012345678901234567890;

SetPrecision[ToExpression[ToString[int] <> "." <> ToString[fra]], 
StringLength[ToString[int]] + StringLength[ToString[fra]]]
```

is still a number,

```
1.234567890123456789012345678900123456789012345678901234567890*10^30
```

now look at it as a string with all digits minutely preserved

```
ScientificForm[%, ExponentStep -> StringLength[ToString[int]]]  

1234567890123456789012345678900.123456789012345678901234567890
```

Comment: I wonder if [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9930/204) would be useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

I use the routine below to convert long numbers to strings to store them on a database in a simple string format.  `ToExpression` can be used to convert the strings back to numbers when needed.

```
longform[num_] := Module[{string, split, exp, sig, len},
  If[IntegerQ[num], ToString[num],
   (* Construct string according to InputForm *)
   string = ToString[InputForm[num]];
   If[StringFreeQ[string, "*"], string,
    split = StringSplit[string, {".", "`", "*"}];
    exp = ToExpression[StringDrop[Last[split], 1]];
    sig = StringJoin[Part[split, 1], Part[split, 2]];
    len = StringLength[Part[split, 2]];
    If[exp < 0, If[num < 0,
      StringJoin["-0.", ConstantArray["0", -exp - 1], StringDrop[sig, 1]],
      StringJoin["0.", ConstantArray["0", -exp - 1], sig]],
     If[exp > len, StringJoin[sig, ConstantArray["0", exp - len], "."],
      StringInsert[sig, ".", exp + If[num < 0, 3, 2]]]]]]]

a = 123456789012345678901234567.123456789012345678901234567;

ans = longform[a]
```

> 123456789012345678901234567.123456789012345678901234567

```
{int, fra} = {#1 <> ".", "." <> #2} & @@ StringSplit[ans, "."];
Grid[{{"int =", int}, {"fra =", fra}}]
Print[Row[{"pre = ", StringLength[int <> fra] - 2}]]
```

> int = 123456789012345678901234567.
>
> fra = .123456789012345678901234567
>
> pre = 54

Comment: Looks very terrible frightening.   .   .Meet it with a good armour.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get you exactly, but if you want a list of integer digits from a Real number you can use `RealDigits`:

```
 {int, fra} = RealDigits[a, 10, 54] // {#[[1]][[1 ;; #[[2]]]], #[[1]][[#[[2]] + 1 ;;]]} &
```

If you then need them as numbers as you posted you can use

```
 FromDigits[int]
 FromDigits[fra] 10^-Length[fra] // N
```

> 123456789012345678901234567
>
> 0.1234567890123457

Comment: You want to produce a couple of numbers. Like the one shown.   .   .You like to build this numbers from parameters as shown.   .  .So you get this kind of long numbers as shown.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're having precision problems:

```
a   = 123456789012345678901234567.123456789012345678901234567 ;
int = 123456789012345678901234567. ;
fra = .123456789012345678901234567 ;
pre = 54 ;

Precision /@ {a, int, fra, int + fra}
```

> {53.0915, 26.0915, 26.0915, 26.0915}

Note that `a` has much higher precision than `int + fra`.  You can use `Round` to establish `int` as a proper Integer:

```
Precision[ Round[int] + fra ]
```

> 53.0915

Therefore use:

```
AccountingForm[Round[int] + fra, pre]
```

> 123456789012345678901234567.12345678901234567890123457

Comment: OK.   .   .I am quit lucky whit this.  .  .The last fraction digit is not as expected. It is 57 here but should be a 567.