# Export number as formatted numeric value, not string

Tags: export, formatting, csv-format, json-format

Some related questions include [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17681/how-to-format-a-large-number).

Is there a way to format numbers for export in CSV or JSON as numbers - not strings -  with a specified number of decimal places and *no* exponentials?

Is output similar to the C language printf:

```
printf("%3.2f\n",d);
```

The closest Mathematica equivalent seems to be `AccountingForm` but even this wraps `AccountingForm` head around the number and so has to be converted to string - whereas converting to expression reverts to exponentials (for larger numbers)

```
formatNumber[n_]:= ToString[AccountingForm[n, {15, 2}, NumberSigns -> {"-", ""}, 
   NumberPadding -> {"", "0"}]];
```

Comment: you can work with `NumberForm` with `ExponentStep -> Infinity`. Pretty much the same, but you don't need the `NumberSigns` option.

Comment: @george2079, problem is, `NumberForm` also adds a head, so how to get around the need for `ToString` ?  - If, instead, `ToExpression` gives an error as NumberForm "is not a string or box. "

Comment: that's why I said pretty much the same.. more discussion here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/970/2079

Comment: @george2079, thanks for the link. However, that Q is general about riffling strings, whereas my Q is more specific about formatting floating point numbers. Are you aware of implementation to handle "%3.2f" format?