# Printing mathematica output without superfluous characters or data

Tags: output-formatting

I have a mathematica script computing a list of numbers to high precision (5000 digits) which I would like to input into another program. I am running mathematica from the terminal to generate the file.

If I just ask for the output directly, the file it creates has a lot of superfluous return characters and ">" characters which would be very painful to remove.

If I ask for the output in  "InputForm" it is cleaner, but it includes information about the precision which is also painful to remove.

> Is there a way to generate the output in a clean way for other uses? Here I simply want to generate a list of numbers (comma separated is fine) in decimal notation. Note that I have to run this in a terminal window since it is a long computation on a remove machine, not to mention that the output is extremely long.

Here is an example file (foo) and example output (foo.out) generated by (math < foo > foo.out)

Input:

```
Table[N[y[n], 200], {n, 1, 3}];
InputForm[Table[N[y[n], 200], {n, 1, 3}]]
```

Output:

```
In[1]:= 
In[2]:= In[2]:= 
Out[2]= {0.585786437626904951198311275790301921430328124623051926823320262009\
 
>     26752153789296114961246567235842726498615376908770297507516394414926278\
 
>     735587850290006416858677733407249440724420004949884721793942853, 
 
>    0.4309644062711508251997185459650503202383880207705086544705533770015445\
 
>     86922982160191602077612059737877497692294847950495845860657358210464559\
 
>     31308381667736143112955567874906787403334158314120298990475, 
 
>    0.3292893218813452475599155637895150960715164062311525963411660131004633\
 
>     76076894648057480623283617921363249307688454385148753758197207463139367\
 
>     79392514500320842933886670362472036221000247494236089697143}

In[3]:= In[3]:= 
Out[3]//InputForm= 
{0.58578643762690495119831127579030192143032812462305192682332026200926752153\
78929611496124656723584272649861537690877029750751639441492627873558785029000\
6416858677733407249440724420004949884721793942852989044002839`200., 0.4309644\
06271150825199718545965050320238388020770508654470553377001544586922982160191\
60207761205973787749769229484795049584586065735821046455931308381667736143112\
955567874906787403334158314120298990475498174000474`200., 0.32928932188134524\
75599155637895150960715164062311525963411660131004633760768946480574806232836\
17921363249307688454385148753758197207463139367793925145003208429338866703624\
72036221000247494236089697142649452200142`200.}

In[4]:=
```

I tried Daniel Huber's suggestion, but the output file I got was different (Full disclosure, I used Export["test.txt", d] instead. I am using Mathematica 12.3.1 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit).

```
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899
86280348253421170679821480865191976`100.
2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772407663035354759
45713821785251664274274661651602106`100.
1.14472988584940017414342735135305871164729481291531157151362307147213776988482607
97836232702754897077020098122305809`100.
```

Comment: Modern approach to this would probably be to use the `wolframscript` command and `ExportString` format of your choosing. For instance, `wolframscript -code 'ExportString[N[Pi, 5000], "CSV"]' > foo.out` or with the corresponding code in file `foo` with `wolframscript -file foo > foo.out`

Comment: Some methods to process your output here: [How to format a large Number](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17681/363)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example. I am using a list with 3 elements and I output 100 digits to a file:

```
d = N[{Pi, E, Log[Pi]}, 100];
Export["d:/tmp/test.txt", ToString@d]
```

The file looks like:

[image]

To reimport it into MMA:

```
Import["d:/tmp/test.txt", "List"][[1]] // ToExpression
```

and you will get a list of the original numbers.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm still getting extra characters which record the number of digits of accuracy (I edited my question since when I tried to write the output as a comment it was a mess)

Comment: Add "ToString", that should fix it. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: Ugh, 24 hours of computation and I get I mess. These numbers are smallish (less than $1$ but bigger than $10^{-100}$ but if you type: d:=N[Pi/10^100,100]; and then ToString@d you get a mess.

Comment: "ToSTring" only works o.k. for numbers without exponents. For small numbers that needs exponents we need a format that displays the exponent on the same line, that is 1D. You may e.g. use "FortranForm" or "CForm" for this purpose. Or you can define a format yourself like e.g.: NumberForm[data, NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "^", #3}] &)]